# PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity **User** :

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
...}
```

And I'm trying to remove a user from a task the database with  :

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM Collaborator c WHERE c.user = :userId AND c.task = :taskId")
void deleteUserFromTask(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("taskId") Long taskId);
```

and this is the relation between User and Collaborator(the table I'm deleting from) : 
  In **User**

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Collaborator> collaborators = new HashSet<>();
```

In **Collaborator**

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,
                      CascadeType.DETACH,
                      CascadeType.REFRESH }, 
           fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserID", nullable = true)
private User user;
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long gestionprojet.java.entities.beans.User.id] by reflection for persistent property [gestionprojet.java.entities.beans.User#id] : 1
```

> Hibernate Version : 5.2.6.FINAL

Comment: Either Change to c.user.id = :userId or pass in User and use c.user = :user

Comment: Put it as answer and i'll accept it, Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a mismatch in your parameters i.e you try and specify a Long as the parameter for a User type:

You change it in one of two ways:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Collaborator c WHERE c.user.id = :userId AND c.task.id = :taskId")
void deleteUserFromTask(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("taskId") Long taskId);
```

or

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Collaborator c WHERE c.user = :user AND c.task = :task")
void deleteUserFromTask(@Param("user") User user, @Param("task") Task task);
```