# Hibernate: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Im Trying to insert an entry in my MySQL-database using hibernate. But I'm getting an IllegalArgumentException.
The id is a primary key in my database and I checked the autoincrement option.

[image]

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public int com.nexus.tutorial.Items.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.nexus.tutorial.Items#id] : Items [name=test, price=20.0, lagerstand=5, anfver=ankauf, position=0,0,0]
...
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.nexus.tutorial.Items.id to com.nexus.tutorial.Items
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java:574)
        at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:62)
```

```
public class HibernateUpdate {

    public static void update(Items item) {

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure("C:\\Users\\N3XUS\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\config\\hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Items.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            System.out.println("Creating new Items");
            session.beginTransaction();
            //List<Items> itemList = session.createQuery("from Items").list();
            session.save(item);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        }finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

this is how I call the method:

```
HibernateUpdate.update(new Items("test", 20.00, 5,"ankauf","0,0,0"));
```

and this is my Model:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="items")
public class Items {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name="price")
    public double price;

    @Column(name="lagerstand")
    public int lagerstand;

    @Column(name="anfver")
    public String anfver;

    @Column(name="position")
    public String position;

    public Items() {

    }

    public Items(String name, double price, int lagerstand, String anfver, String position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.lagerstand = lagerstand;
        this.anfver = anfver;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getLagerstand() {
        return lagerstand;
    }

    public void setLagerstand(int lagerstand) {
        this.lagerstand = lagerstand;
    }

    public String getAnfver() {
        return anfver;
    }

    public void setAnfver(String anfver) {
        this.anfver = anfver;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Items [name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", lagerstand=" + lagerstand + ", anfver=" + anfver
                + ", position=" + position + "]";
    }

}
```

The modifier should be private I know. I'm using the latest versions for JDBC and hibernate from the maven-repository.

```
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-agroal:5.3.10.Final'
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.15'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `GeneratedValue` to ensure that your id is auto increment :

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
public int id;
```

after this your ID is auto increment and you can add your item :

```
HibernateUpdate.update(new Items("test", 20.00, 5,"ankauf","0,0,0"));
```

> Advice: your attributes in preference must be private or protected and
>   from getter and setter you can access to them.

Comment: I tryed this out but I still get the same Error. I also tryed diffrent generationstypes. But I don't think that this is the problem because I have an example progrogramm using hibernate and the Id and Column Annotation was allways enough to autogenerate and increment  IDs.

Comment: Oh wait thats not true. The Error is a bit diffrent now not the id but the anfver field has this error: ```rg.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.nexus.tutorial.Items.anfver] by reflection for persistent property [com.nexus.tutorial.Items#anfver] : Items [name=name, price=20.0, lagerstand=50, anfver=test, position=test]  caused by Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.nexus.tutorial.Items.anfver to com.nexus.tutorial.Items```

Comment: Try returnig this.anfver in your getter public String getAnfver() { return this.anfver; }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642939/propertyaccessexception-error-accessing-field

Comment: Thats a diffrent problem

Comment: Show me your hibernate cfg.