# Getting error while fetching data in Spring data JPA for OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables named users and doctors and also corressponding JPA entities. Users table has column user_name(unique key, not a primary key) and which is acting as foreign key in doctors table. while fetching data from users table getting below error.

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.api.user.domain.UserEntity.userName] by reflection for persistent property [com.api.user.domain.UserEntity#userName] : 95754
```

Below are the JPA entities and repository.
JPA Entity - UserEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity extends GenericEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "_id")
    private Long _id;
    
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userEntity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH) 
    private DoctorEntity doctorEntity;
}
```

JPA Entity - DoctorEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctors")
public class DoctorEntity extends GenericEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="_id")
    private Integer _id;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_name", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "user_name")
    private UserEntity userEntity; 
}
```

JPA Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepo extends GenericRepo<UserEntity, Long> {
    public UserEntity findByUserName(String userName);
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepo<GenericEntity, Object> extends JpaRepository<GenericEntity, Object> {

}
```

Please help, Thanks

Comment: From the error log, it seems you need Getter setter for the entity classes or Use lombok's `@Getter`, `@Setter` annotation.

Comment: I am already using Lombok, not an issue with getter setter.

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642939/propertyaccessexception-error-accessing-field , If not can you please provide more details like how you are fetching it and what is there in your GenericEntity ?